Socket.io server emitting an empty array to the client
In the input box of my app, I type a message and expect the message to be transmitted to the server and then transmitted back to the client so as to map the information to my UI.
While transmitting to the server seems to be working correctly, getting back the information from the socket.io server does not seem to work and returns an empty array.
Now the thing is when I input a message the first time, the server returns an empty array but when I input another message, the server now returns an array with one object instead of two. Also, the object it returns is the first message I typed initially and not the new one.
To sum everything up, server returns one object lesser than what it was given and what it returns is what it was given initially and not the new information.
This is the client console at the first instant. The information passed is in the server console.
This is the server console at the first instant which appears to work correctly
Here is the client console at the second instant which returns what was passed in the first instance
This is the server console at the second instant which also appear to work correctly
Here is the client code:
'use client'

import { io } from 'socket.io-client'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { ChatSenderBox } from './ChatBox'
import { ChatRecieverBox } from './ChatBox'
import MessageInput from './MessageInput'


const ChatContainer = ({username, userImage}) => {

  const [socket, setSocket] = useState(undefined)
  const [allInfo, setAllInfo] = useState([])

  // sending all info to the socket
  const sendChatToServer = (chat) => {
    socket.emit('chat', chat)
  }

  //getting back the emitted message
  useEffect(()=>{
    const socket = io('http://localhost:3001')

    socket.on('chat', (chatRecieved) => {
      setAllInfo(chatRecieved)
    })

    setSocket(socket)
  }, [])

  // This is a function passed as prop to the messageInput component
  const addMessage = (chat) => {
    const newChat = {...chat, username, userImage}

    if(newChat.message !== ''){

      setAllInfo([...allInfo, newChat])
  
      sendChatToServer([...allInfo, newChat])

      console.log(allInfo)
    } 
  }

  const ChatsArrangement = ({ data, username }) => {

    if(username === data.username){
      return data.map((info, index) => (
          <ChatSenderBox 
            key={index} 
            username={info.username} 
            profilePic={info.userImage} 
            message={info.message} 
          />
      ))
    } else{
      return data.map((info, index) => (
          <ChatRecieverBox 
            key={index} 
            username={info.username} 
            profilePic={info.userImage} 
            message={info.message} 
          />
      ));
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className=' w-full h-full p-4 chatPage z-100'>
        {allInfo.length && <ChatsArrangement data={allInfo} username={username}/>}
      </div>
      <MessageInput addMessage={addMessage}/>
    </>
  )
}

export default ChatContainer

And this is the server code:
const express = require("express")
const http = require("http")
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const app = express()

const server = http.createServer(app)
const io = new Server(server, {
    cors:{
        origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
        methods: ["GET", "POST"]
    }
})

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log("A user is connected")

    // messaged recieved and sent back to the client.
    socket.on("chat", (chat)=>{
        if(chat.lenght){
            io.emit("chat", chat)
        }
        console.log(chat)
    })

    socket.on("disconnect", ()=>{
        console.log("A user disconnected")
    })
})

server.listen(3001, () => console.log('listening to port 3001'))


try to useEffect or console.log outside of setState

Actually your code works fine, the problem is in the placement of console
In react setState here (setAllInfo) function is asynchronous, so the state changes won't be applied immediately. That's why the console after setState still in old value.
Solution
Simply try to console outside of setState or use useEffect and add the value as dependency
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(allInfo); // Updated value here
}, [allInfo]);

Also there is an issue in your react component, you have to use either inline js or pass allinfo as a prop like below.

Inline condition
 return (
     <div className=" w-full h-full p-4 chatPage">
         {allInfo.length &&
             allInfo.map((info, index) => (
                 <ChatSenderBox
                     key={index}
                     username={info.username}
                     profilePic={info.userImage}
                     message={info.message}
                 />
             ))}
         <MessageInput addMessage={addMessage} />
     </div>
 );


Or pass allinfo as prop the component ChatsArrangment so it can render whenever the allinfo changes.
 const ChatsArrangment = (data) => {
     return data.map((info, index) => (
         <ChatSenderBox key={index} username={info.username} profilePic={info.userImage} message={info.message} />
     ));
 };

 return (
     <div className=" w-full h-full p-4 chatPage">
         {allinfo.length && <ChatsArrangment data={allinfo} />}
         <MessageInput addMessage={addMessage} />
     </div>
 );




Thank you, your solution works perfectly as regards getting the updated value in the in the console. However mapping the array to my UI still appears to be a hassle, it still for some reason not mapping to the UI. Please share your insight. Thank you

Hassle means, the code seems good ?

I mean I cannot map the array into my UI. it is not displaying. The array only displays in the console but not in the UI.

your solution works, but i still cannot map the allInfo array to my UI

I've update the answer, you have to pass allinfo as  a prop

Thank you Sir for your time. I can now map to the UI. But I want to ask one last thing please. The (if conditional statement) in the client code above does not work. I got the (username and userImage) parameters from Clerk auth. Can you please take a look Sir?

I have also updated the client code above. I passed the data and the (username) I got from clerk as props to the ChatArrangement component

Thank you for your help Sir. I've been able to solve the problem
